# Failed to create JVM in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, jvm

I set the JAVA_HOME and PATH in environment variables but now android studio is giving to me a new error.
here is error:

```
Failed to create JVM:error code -6.
JVM path:C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.9.0
if you already have a 64-bit JDKinstalled, define a JAVA_HOME variable in
```

[image]

Comment: You need an installation of JDK v1.7. See my answer below.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [failed to create jvm error code 4 android studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33094132/failed-to-create-jvm-error-code-4-android-studio)

Comment: I have also [answered on another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66532284/5376073) what was working for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At this point in time, Android supports up to JDK v1.7. See [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) for more technical info.

You can get the latest JDK v1.7 release 79 [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).

Note: You can have multiple JDK versions installed on your computer, but you need your `JAVA_HOME` variable to point to the installation of JDK v1.7 for Android Studio to work:

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79
```

Also, remember to download the correct 32-bit or 64-bit version of JDK v1.7 for your current operating system.

Answer (score 1):

I hit this problem on my Windows 10 computer after updating my vm settings. The only way I managed to solve this was to remove my Android Studio config data:-

```
C:\Users\myuseraccount\.AndroidStudio2.2
```

I literally removed this entire folder and everything worked well again.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall and reinstall again, then set the `JAVA_HOME` variable again.

Reference: https://youtu.be/ccWyL0QPLUc

Answer (score -2):

do you have jdk 32-bit and 64-bit installed on your computer , if so try to install one of them and only one